# Теряется стек вызовов при async/await

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

При отладке и генерации исключения я иногда вижу довольно бедных стек вызова и не могу выбраться к месту откуда произошел вызов... А когда ниже по стеку помечается, как External...

Это как-то можно поправить?

Comment: Насколько я помню, трассировка возможна только до метода, где находится `catch`.

Comment: Если вы отлаживаете это хорошо. Если код по стеку вам не помогает то старайтесь уловить код до ошибки. У  вас в стеке лежит очередь вызовов нужно разобраться и поставить точку останова до ошибки